# Aldryn NewsBlog Designing a Template

Tags: html, django, templates, jinja2

The documentation for aldryn news-blog is very vague and i don't understand how to use articles.

I'm trying to make a section page where each instance of an article creates a panel with the article's featured image and the name as the footer which will also be a button. Each article will create a new column. When there is 4 articles in a column, a new row will be started for the next article.

[Aldryn-Newsblog/models](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog/blob/master/aldryn_newsblog/models.py)

[Aldryn-Newsblog/views](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog/blob/master/aldryn_newsblog/views.py)

When I run this code, nothing shows up on the page even though I have 6 articles with featured images.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this.
Django V- 1.8

```
 {% load i18n staticfiles thumbnail cms_tags apphooks_config_tags %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {% for article in article_list %}
      <div class="col-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">

          <div class=panel-body>
              <img src="{% thumbnail article.featured_image 800x450 crop subject_location=article.featured_image.subject_location %}" alt="{{ article.featured_image.alt }}">
          </div>
          <div class=panel-footer>
              <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block aria-pressed=False label={{ article.slug_source.fieldname }}">
         </div>
          {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}
          </div>
           <div class="row">
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor%}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your if condition should be like

```
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}
```

see [divisibelby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) in documentation.

your code for adding row after every 4 article should be

```
{% extends "aldryn_newsblog/base.html" %}
{% load i18n staticfiles thumbnail cms_tags apphooks_config_tags %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {% for article in article_list %}
      <div class="col-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class=panel-body>
              <img src="{% thumbnail article.featured_image 800x450 crop subject_location=article.featured_image.subject_location %}" alt="{{ article.featured_image.alt }}">
          </div>
          <div class=panel-footer>
              <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-light btn-lg btn-block" aria-pressed=False>{{ article.slug_source_field_name }}</a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
         {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.last %}
          </div>
           <div class="row">
         {% elif %}
            </div>
         {% endif %}
      {% empty %}
        <p>{% trans "No items available" %}</p>
      {% endfor%}
    </div>
</div>
```

now everything should work fine assuming you are calling right view for right url and rendering right template.

as stated in its [document](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog/blob/master/docs/how-to/apphook_configurations.rst#fields), if you want to hook your custom template then create a directory **custom-directory** under

> templates/aldryn_newsblog/custom-directory/article_list.html

Comment: This fixed the loop problem (without the ")" after counter0) but now none of the articles will display

Comment: partly. It does not display the articles. The divisibleby was part of the solution to fix the loop counter the second part of the question was how could I get it to display.

Comment: could you please raise another question for that with proper code including model and view ?

Comment: edited my answer. and everything should work as expected.

Comment: hey, did you find the solution ?

Comment: What you put was really extremely helpful and exactly what I asked for. My current problem is putting this template within the right folder, making sure the views and urls are correct. Thank you!

Comment: updated again, code sample as well as answer. please compare and also if this help you please upvote and accept :) thanks.